# Access External webpage HTML table without table ID from Java Script and convert to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, html-table

I have written a script to get HTML table data to JSON Object.

for this task I have used [lightswitch05](http://lightswitch05.github.io/table-to-json/javascripts/jquery.tabletojson.min.js) jquery plugin.

In this code I can access a HTML table data in same web page in Javascript
using

`var table = $('#example-table').tableToJSON();`

but I need to access HTML table of external webpage.
Table URL is here - http://ccmcwolf.byethost4.com/index.html

how can I change the it to above "#example-table"  to that external web page table ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script
src="http://lightswitch05.github.io/table-to-json/javascripts/jquery.tabletojson.min.js">
</script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
   var table = $('#example-table').tableToJSON();
  console.log(table);
  alert(JSON.stringify(table));  
    }
$(document).ready(myFunction);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id='example-table' class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th data-override="Score">Points</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td data-override="disqualified">50</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, JavaScript has scope in the current page only (i.e. it can access and modify the content of the page where it is embedded or declared/linked using the script tag), I don't think there is any direct way of doing it.

But if that external page is on the same domain where your current JavaScript code is operating, you can always get the html by an Ajax call to the server and then run your code to extract the html table in JSON form.

Please, let me know if I am missing something and I will edit my answer based on your input.

Thank you.